# Insert a photo to a Word bookmark from an Excel range, VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to build a report generator using an excel database. I would like to insert photos into word bookmarks from an HTML link. I am wondering if it is possible to do this?

Right now my code is set up to test if I can insert the photos from the HTML link alone. Here is what it looks like:

```
Sub photobomb

Dim imagePath As String
imagePath ="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/uywzy5yf08apk68/130%20Boreal%20Avenuexx.jpg"

 With ActiveDocument

    .Bookmarks("imagePath1").Range
    .InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= "imagePath", _
    LinkToFile:=False, _
    SaveWithDocument:=False, _

End With

End Sub
```

The code keeps failing. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because your code is slightly incorrect. Also `imagePath` is a variable. When you put it within `Quotes`, it becomes a string. Since I don't have access to the picture link mentioned in your post, I am using a different link.

Try this (**In MS Word**)

```
Sub photobomb()
    Dim imagePath As String

    imagePath = "https://www.dropbox.com/static/images/lockbox.png"

    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("imagePath1").Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=imagePath
End Sub
```

Now all you need to do is LateBind/EarlyBind from Excel to Word and use the above code.

Here is small example which is **Untested**. Paste this code in an Excel module and run it

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oWordApp As Object, oWordDoc As Object
    Dim FlName As String
    Dim imagePath As String

    '~~> Change link and path accordingly
    imagePath = "https://www.dropbox.com/static/images/lockbox.png"
    FlName = "C:\MyFile.Docx"

    '~~> Establish an Word application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    oWordApp.Visible = True

    Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(FlName)

    oWordDoc.Bookmarks("imagePath1").Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture Filename:=imagePath
End Sub
```